# Equivalent of a chief minister in USA?

Tags: united-states, india

In countries like India and Australia, we have the concept of a [Chief minister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_Minister). I wanted to know what is the equivalent position in USA? Since all these countries have states.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The head of government of a US state is known as a governor. It's not quite equivalent to a chief minister, as governors are elected in their own right and are not members of the legislature, nor are they formally responsible to the legislature in the same way that ministers of a Westminster-style government are.

Comment: Just an add on, I believe the Canadian and Australian equivalent are called "Premiers" as they are Federal nations with Westminster-Style governments (Australia is actually more a hybrid of Westminster and American some times called Washinminster.  The difference is the Aussie Upper house (the Senate) has more political powers than traditional Westminster Style Upper Houses).